# Show that there exists an $m \in N$ such that $T^m = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T \in B(X)$ have the property that for every $x \in X$
there is an $n \in N$ such that $T^n(x) = 0$. The book asks me to show that there exists an $m \in N$ such that $T^m = 0$.

I was told that I can use Baire's theorem to show the above. I only have problems applying it to this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C_n=\{x \in X \mid T^n(x)=0\}$. By assumption, we have that $\bigcup_n C_n=X$, and clearly the $C_n$ are closed sets (by continuity of $T$). From Baire's theorem, there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $x_0 \in X, r>0$ such that the open ball $B(x_0, r)$ is all contained in $C_m$.

From this is direct to check that $T^m$ is zero: if $\lVert v\rVert < r$, then
$$ T(v)=T(x_0+v)-T(x_0)=0-0=0. $$
This way, $T^m(v)=0$ for all $\lVert v\rVert<r$. As $T^m$ is linear, this implies that $T^m=0$, as required.